# Multiple Drop downs the item which is selected in one drop down should not be available in another drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have multiple drop downs on which I `loop` to get the values from `database` and display them into the drop down, suppose I have four drop downs each drop down contains values from 1 to 4, what I need is if user select "1" from "drop down 1" then other drop downs should not have 1 present in it, means only 1 is selected once from these four drop downs. If user select "4" from "drop down 2" then 4 will not be available in other three drop downs, 
How can I achieve this functionality from `jQuery`?

The snapshot below will be ranking from 1 to 4 it should be ranked from 1 to 4, so user can select 1 item and this item will not be selected from others.

[image: This snapshot will give you proper understanding]

You can see a full demo in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/husnain/amthbdk3/).

**Edit**
See the error now the last dropdown is empty, its not showing any thing. 
[image]

Comment: How come it's possible that your screenshot showing '4' and '2' in two dropdowns at the same time which infact conflict  your logic.. Will the logic work only on change?

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the values or just disable the selected values so that they can be enabled later if the selection changes..?

Comment: @PrashantKumar the values that you seen are randomly selected by me, each drop down contains values from 1 to 4, you can check the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/husnain/amthbdk3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ll prefer doing it this way :

```
$("select").on('focus', function () {
    previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
         $("select[value="+$(this).val()+"]").not(this).val(previous);
    });
```

Whenever the user choose a value, you select the `<select>` element with the same value and switch them.

Moreover, there is a restriction. You have to load the page with distinctive values for each select element as I did in the fiddle below.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zadczhwx/)

The `previous` variable gets the old value of the select before change, so you can use it to set the value of the select which have the same value as your target select.

Comment: Your logic is really awesome but the code is not working on my site. :(

Comment: its not swapping itself please suggest?

Comment: make sure you have added `selected`attribute in your select tags as I did, look closer in the fiddle above.

Comment: Yes I have already added the selected attribute, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is that when you select any option from any of your dropdownlists you'll have to remove that option from the rest of the lists except the one you selected from. Try this way,

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    $("select").not(this).children("option:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").remove();
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/mqr6g32p/)

***References :*** 
[***.not()***](http://api.jquery.com/not/) , 
[***.children()***](http://api.jquery.com/children/) , [***:contains()***](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/),  [***.remove()***](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

[***Note :*** No two or more elements should have same *id*. In such situation you should use *class* . OP's markup need to be updated.]

***Another Option :***

If you don't want to remove the options and want to reset these whenever you want then you can hide the options and on reset show them all. Simply add the following HTML & jQuery in your code.

***HTML :***

```
// reset button
<button id="resetddls">Reset</button>
```

***jQuery :***

```
// here you are hiding the selected option from rest of the ddls not removing.
$("select").on("change", function(){
    $("select").not(this).children("option:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").hide();
});

$("#resetddls").on("click", function(){
    $("select option").show();
});
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/wac2ob53/)

Comment: any specific reason? I appreciate an explanation about the wrong.

Comment: thank you for your code, but the problem is when i select all the drop downs, after that its not working properly. if i select the drop downs and then i want to re change the order then it creates problem please suggest.

Comment: do explain "its not working properly" , "re change order" and also "it creates problem".

Comment: Mean to say first time its working as i needed, when i complete the selection, and after that I re change the values then it creates problems, as @Faruk Omar included the reset functionality, but still the problem exists,

Comment: so, do you want when you click on reset every select element will get there initial value back? and about the empty select element if you select each option from one select isn't it obvious that other select elements will be empty!

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to re change after giving once  , according to **Ashad Shanto** comments . I gave a reset box. And disabled instead of remove

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="questions">
            <input type="hidden" name="questions[9][id]" value="85" class="ui-wizard-content">
            <input type="hidden" name="questions[9][option_type]" value="dropdown" class="ui-wizard-content">
            <h3>Question 10</h3>

            <p></p><p>this is an example question for testing rankings.&nbsp;</p>
            <p><input type="checkbox" id="resetoption" /> Reset Option</p>
            <div class="checkbox" id="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="return false" class="required ui-wizard-content" name="questions[9][option]" value="372">
                    Rank1                                            </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="ui-wizard-content valid">

                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox" id="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="return false" class="required ui-wizard-content" name="questions[9][option]" value="373">
                    Rank2                                            </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="ui-wizard-content valid">

                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox" id="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="return false" class="required ui-wizard-content" name="questions[9][option]" value="374">
                    Rank3                                            </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="ui-wizard-content valid">

                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox" id="">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" onclick="return false" class="required ui-wizard-content" name="questions[9][option]" value="375">
                    Rank4                                            </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="ui-wizard-content valid">

                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script>
            $('#resetoption').on('click', function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $("select").children("option").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });

                $("select").on('change', function () {
                $("select").not(this).children("option:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no two or more HTML element should be identified with same id. Id should be unique. You can use class if you need point to group of elements at once.

Comment: Ops i copied this html from ***Revolution* [refrence](http://jsfiddle.net/husnain/amthbdk3/). Ok i am editing

Answer (score -1):

`maintain one array which are got selected already in angularjs`

```
     <select ng-model="obj.subject" on-change="selectedItem(obj.subject)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-if="selectedArray.indexOf(obj.id)===-1||obj.id === obj.subject" ng- 
     repeat="obj in list" 
       value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.subject}} 
    </option>
    </select>
    <select ng-model="obj.subject1" on-change="selectedItem(obj.subject)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-if="selectedArray.indexOf(obj.id)===-1||obj.id === obj.subject1"
    ng-repeat="obj in list" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.subject}}</option>
    </select>
   <select ng-model="obj.subject2" on-change="selectedItem(obj.subject)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-if="selectedArray.indexOf(obj.id)===-1||obj.id === obj.subject2"
    ng-repeat="obj in list" value="{{obj.id}}">{{obj.subject}}</option>
    </select>

   <script>
   $scope.list = [
    {
      id:1,
      subject:"physics"
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:"chemistry"
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:"maths"
    }

   ];
    $scope.obj = {};
    $scope.selectedArray = [];
    $scope.selectedItem = function (){
     $scope.selectedArray = [];
     $scope.selectedArray.push(obj.subject);
     $scope.selectedArray.push(obj.subject1);
     $scope.selectedArray.push(obj.subject2);
    }
   </script>
```